# How to print 3 letter words from a list which were taken from a split array VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, printing

I'm trying to print the contents of a list consisting of 3 letter words from an array. The code works but it will print the list multiple times and I am unsure as to why. Can anyone help? i'm building a decryption software using frequency analysis and this step is a crucial part according to my teacher. I'm using a windows form application in visual studio. Below is the code and the result of it.

Private Sub threeLetterWordButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles threeLetterWordButton.Click

```
    freqTextBox.Show()

    Dim threeWordList As New List(Of String)
    Dim encryptedText As String = encryptionInput.Text
    Dim encryptedArrary() As String = Split(encryptedText)

    For Each item In encryptedArrary

        For i = 0 To encryptedArrary.GetUpperBound(0)

            If encryptedArrary(i).Length = 3 Then

                threeWordList.Add(encryptedArrary(i))

                For Each j In threeWordList

                    freqTextBox.Text = freqTextBox.Text & j & " "

                Next

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

[Here is the result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szYET.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the 3 loops. This code will do it with one:

```
For Each item In encryptedArrary
        If item.Length = 3 Then
            threeWordList.Add(item)
            freqTextBox.Text = freqTextBox.Text & item & " "
        End If
Next
```

Comment: @Lauren You don't access the `threeWordList` in this Sub, do you actually need it?

Comment: @ProGrammer Oh yeah i didn't realise in this sub that i don't need it, but i do need it later on in the code but thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

Extending the previous answer, you could reduce the code checking for the length directly into the loop declaration, like this:

```
    For Each item In encryptedArrary.Where(Function(x) x.Length = 3)
        threeWordList.Add(item)
        freqTextBox.Text = freqTextBox.Text & item & " "
    Next
```

That way, you extract the 3-length items previously the loop start, reducing the number of iterations

Comment: Wow that makes it really efficient, thank you!! I'll add that in